# Burning missionary material

Tags: christianity, heresy

I remember learning a while ago that we are supposed to burn missionary material, presumably because it is kefirah.  At one point a local missionary was specifically targeting us and putting it through our letterbox regularly and it was getting quite annoying to keep getting the incinerator bin and blowtorch out (especially if it was raining, and I'm sure the paper was designed to be hard to burn!).

1. Is the mitzva to burn it immediately or is it allowable to wait until it is convenient?
2. Are alternative methods of disposal acceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Status of books printed by the "Society for Distributing Hebrew Scriptures"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/status-of-books-printed-by-the-society-for-distributing-hebrew-scriptures)

Comment: @Deuteronomy no, it only confirms that burning is the normal recommended method, but doesn't answer either of the 2 specific points that I asked about

Comment: re 1, I do not see it as unique to this question and re 2, that is definitely discussed in the answers of that question

Comment: @Deuteronomy 1 I think is important because there may be a mitzva to destroy something like this more urgently than doing other mitzvahs as it is dangerous.  2 is sort of touched on, but that's in the context of "problematic books", which may or may not be the same as outright missionary material.  I don't feel that a clear answer is given there.

Comment: Someone I knew once asked Rabbi Aharon Feldman shlit"a about some material that fell into his possession. He was told that while burning is preferable, it is more important to immediately get rid of it, so to just throw it out.